# Excel Macro: SEARCH in Range (M2:M100) for how many chars before "-" if 3 then run else if 4 then run

Tags: vba, excel

How can VBA look in a certain range and count how many characters before the first hyphen "-" if it's 3 then run a sub, I've written `else if` it's 4 then run another sub?

I don't care what text it is just how many characters before only the first "-"
Examples of the 2 types of text in the range

```
D10-AA-02A-P2 = 3 '**D10**

C047-AB-V34 AD-P2 > V34-AD-C047 AB-P14 = 4 '**C047**
```

Comment: The basic looping structure of both provided answers should work for you, but they're working far too hard to identify where the dash is. It would be much more simple to use `If Instr(1, <cell text>, "-") = [3|4]` to identify where the `-` is located. No need to call worksheet functions or `.Find()` or `.Search()`. (NOTE: replace `<cell text>` with the appropriate item from the loop structure you've chosen, and `[3|4]` should be the single digit you're looking for in that particular instance.)

Comment: I suggest you to use `Instr()` as is a public function in VBA ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WorksheetFunction.Search` or `WorksheetFunction.Find`

```
Sub test()
    Dim Cl As Range
    For Each Cl In Sheets("PAR_import").[M3:M100]
        If Cl.Text Like "*-*" Then
            If WorksheetFunction.Search("-", Cl.Text) - 1 = 3 Then
                Call SubX
            ElseIf WorksheetFunction.Search("-", Cl.Text) - 1 = 4 Then
                Call SubY
            End If
        End If
    Next Cl
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help i have tried this option, but if i am reading it correctly it looks like its looking for the number 3 or number 4 ? when i wish to count the number of text characters before the hyphen, therefore it has returned intermittent results. I am new to scripting so forgive me if i am mistaken i am still getting my head around this fantastic language.

Comment: @SharifMohamed this code do exactly what you asking for, it count the characters before `"-"` and if count of chars before `"-"` equal to 3 it run SubX if equal to 4 it run SubY

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work:

```
Sub SwitchSub()
    Dim rng as Range, cl as Range, CharsBeforeHyphen As String

    Set rng = Worksheets("PAR_import").Range("M3:M100")

    For each cl in rng
        CharsBeforeHyphen = VBA.Left$(cl, Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("-", cl, 1) - 1)

        If VBA.Len(CharsBeforeHyphen) = 3 Then
            Call SubX
        ElseIf VBA.Len(CharsBeforeHyphen) = 4 Then
            Call SubY
        End If
    next cl
End Sub
```

You can modify the code to pass in the range reference as you see fit.

Comment: Perfect Exactly what i was looking for, forgot to mention i need it to lookup in a spcific worksheet     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR_import").Range(M3:M100)

Comment: CharsBeforeHyphen = VBA.Left$(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR_import").Range("M3:M100"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("-", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PAR_import").Range("M3:M100"), 1) - 1)  ???

Comment: Do you mean you want to loop over the range `M3:M100`, check the number of digits for each cell, and then call appropriate sub?

Comment: Yes just your code is perfect except i think i went wrong somewhere with the reference to the worksheet range. as its debug erroring

Comment: See my edit - now loops over each cell in the range on the other worksheet

Comment: Hi thanks for your help im now getting ... unable to get the find property of the worksheet function class .. I need to add an on error because there are some blank cells in the range and they are random but i want it to bypass them on error keep goin ?

Comment: Try adding `On error resume next` just before the `for each` loop.